# Varnish 6 bans_persisted_bytes ballooning, but memory usage is fine

Tags: varnish, memory-usage

In a Varnish 6 server I'm responsible for, there are short bursts of very many bans. These are the result of an application I am not able to modify. This has caused RAM usage to very quickly balloon out of control, but I have been able to fix that by setting `ban_cutoff` to 100. That seems to be doing the trick very well. RAM usage is now very much under control.

However, `bans_persisted_bytes` still grows rapidly each burst and doesn't seem to be going down at all. As I'm writing this it's at about 29GiB but the total memory usage of the host, a Debian Bullseye machine, is at like 1.6 GiB.

Should I be worried about the size of `bans_persisted_bytes`? After all, it doesn't seem to be using RAM. But I have to wonder what the value means if not RAM usage.

I hope someone can shed some light on this. TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am happy to hear that the ban cutoff (which I authored) works for you as intended, I do not think that the answer you gave yourself is correct.

`bans_persisted_bytes` *is* a gauge showing the ban list in bytes, see [varnish-counters(7)](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnish-counters.html). `bans_persisted_fragmentation` is the number of bytes "wasted" for complete and duplicate bans [until they can be removed](https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/4d180a8bc57736290c260155192b2f1f6c5e9a0d/bin/varnishd/cache/cache_ban_lurker.c#L58-L125).

So unless we have a bug, `bans_persisted_bytes` *is* the actual size of your ban list, and if you basically need the cutoff to keep it under control, it is to be expected to be huge.

Comment: Thank you for replying! Great to hear from the horse's mouth. However I think I must be confused as to what the ban list actually is. Because you're saying that the `ban_cleantail` function removes bans, and I don't understand the VTAILQ function calls but can see that counters are being decreased where applicable based on the bit flags, but nowhere in `ban_cleantail` is `bans_persisted_bytes` decreased. If bans are being removed, shouldn't they be struck from the ban list?

Comment: Bans are only ever removed from the tail of the ban list. Bans which are for whatever reason not required any more (e.g. duplicated or fully processed by the ban lurker), are marked as completed (`C` marker in `varnishadm ban.list`).

Comment: When bans are marked completed, their length is added to `bans_persisted_fragmentation` in `ban_mark_completed()`. In `ban_export()`, that counter is deducted from `bans_persisted_bytes`. This is how the `bans_persisted_bytes` shrinks.

Comment: Looking at the `ban_export` function I see how the `bans_persisted_bytes` can shrink now ([GitHub link to the actual spot](https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/6.6/bin/varnishd/cache/cache_ban.c#L340)). I will mark your answer as correct because I see that my answer is wrong now. Thank you for indulging me!

Answer (score 0):

My own below answer turns out to be incorrect. Please refer to the accepted answer instead.

<s>To answer my own question I have perused the source code for Varnish 6.1. It seems to be the same in Varnish 7.2. There are two places where the value `bans_persisted_bytes` is changed, and in both cases a value is added that is guaranteed to be zero or greater.</s>

This means that no matter how big the ban list is, the value `bans_persisted_bytes` will never decrease and should therefore be considered to be a cumulative value.

Given the fact that setting the cutoff value succeeds in curbing the memory footprint, I feel that I can safely conclude that the growth of the value `bans_persisted_bytes` is in fact nothing to worry about.